# Flash not displaying on dreamweaver template based pages

Tags: xml, flash, dreamweaver

I have a test site up [here](http://www.itashowcase.org/dev/index.html) and as you can see, the Flash movie plays fine. But when you navigate to an inside page it does not. The flash movie has an action in the native file that references an xml file to list the images. So why wouldn't the inside pages do the same?

Answer (score 0):

It was a file path problem. Doesn't exactly make sense to me yet but it works.